# How to rename an object's mesh data with Python?

Tags: python, scripting

I know how to rename the transform node.

But I don't know how to access the object data node.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
obj.name = "test"
```

A
What should I do?

[image]

Comment: that one is called mesh BTW, not shape. Shape is another thing.

Comment: It is `data` in a mesh object: `obj.data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should consider to use interactive python console provided in Blender. With Ctrl+space, it will list all possible candidate complete word in current sentence. It will help you guess the desired command that you want. No need to ask at here and wait.

[image]

And the answer: `object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks` is a list of shape key for object.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is helpful, but not correct for this need. To rename the mesh for an object you need to set the `.data.name`. For example:

```py
# set the name for specific mesh
bpy.data.objects['test'].data.name = 'test_mesh'

# set the name of all meshes to be the same as the object
for name, obj in bpy.data.objects.items():
   obj.data.name = name
```